# Merging GeoDataFrames on both Point geometry and other columns at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, shapely, geopandas

How would one go about merging two `GeoDataFrame`s on both `Point` geometry and arbitrary other columns at the same time? I realize this task is ambiguous for all other geometries than `Point` because "equality" is not well defined for Lines and Polygons, but still.

The following MWE throws an error if I simply try `gdf2.merge(gdf)`, correctly complaining that

> unhashable type: 'Point'.

How does one work around this?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import shapely

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
Name Value x y
'a' 1.5 0. 0.
'b' 22  0. 1.
'c' 0.2 0. 1.
'''),sep=r"\s*",engine='python')

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''
Name OtherValue x y
'a' 9.9 0. 0.
'b' 4.5 0. 1.
'c' 2e3 1. 1.
'''),sep=r"\s*",engine='python')

def dataframe_to_geodataframe(df):
    geometry = [shapely.geometry.Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.x, df.y)]
    df = df.drop(['x','y'], axis=1)
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry)
    return gdf

gdf = dataframe_to_geodataframe(df)
gdf2 = dataframe_to_geodataframe(df2)

gdf.merge(gdf2,how='left')
```

Output would ideally be something like

```
  Name  Value     geometry OtherValue
0  'a'    1.5  POINT (0 0)        9.9
1  'b'   22.0  POINT (0 1)        4.5
2  'c'    0.2  POINT (0 1)        NaN
```

(of course depending on the `how` keyword).

(I do realize this can be done easily after converting back to ordinary pandas DataFrames, but I feel there should be a way to do this without converting forth and back.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One (perhaps dirty) way would be to make the `Point` hashable by extending the class `shapely.geometry.Point`:

```
class HPoint(shapely.geometry.Point):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __hash__(self):
       return hash(tuple(self.coords))
```

This is based on the fact that the equality operator for `Point` (provided via the parent class `BaseGeometry`) just [compares](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/5d18af283e485a427d121e05fbf8e9968db4a569/shapely/geometry/base.py#L278) the coordinate tuples.

Then you could use this class as:

```
def dataframe_to_geodataframe(df):
    geometry = [HPoint(xy) for xy in zip(df.x, df.y)]
    df = df.drop(['x','y'], axis=1)
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry)
    return gdf

gdf = dataframe_to_geodataframe(df)
gdf2 = dataframe_to_geodataframe(df2)

print(gdf2.merge(gdf, how='right'))
```

which yields:

```
  Name  OtherValue     geometry  Value
0  'a'         9.9  POINT (0 0)    1.5
1  'b'         4.5  POINT (0 1)   22.0
2  'c'         NaN  POINT (0 1)    0.2
```

Comment: I like this! Follow-up question: What is the advantage of having `Point` etc. **not** hashable in the first place (for geopandas, or generally)?

Comment: @doppler I would say that it leads to the same pitfalls as [hashing](https://diego.assencio.com/?index=67e5393c40a627818513f9bcacd6a70d) raw floats, for example with the implementation above `hash(HPoint(10/6, 1))` is not equal to `hash(HPoint(10*(1/6), 1))`. One would need to either use a spatial join, or as a workaround, round the floating point coordinates to some fixed precision in order to avoid issues as in the previous example...

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. I was considering an `.sjoin()` but it is not clear to me how one would propagate the associated numerical information at the same time.